# How do I get UIView width and height before adding to subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm building a UIPageViewController that has a variable number of pages based on the height of views in an array of views.

I have a class called a `BlockView` that looks like this:

```
final class BlockView: UIView {

    init(viewModel: BlockViewModel) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        let primaryLabel = UILabel()
        primaryLabel.text = viewModel.labelText
        addSubview(primaryLabel)

        constrain(primaryLabel) {
            $0.top == $0.superview!.top + 8
            $0.bottom == $0.superview!.bottom - 8
            $0.left == $0.superview!.left + 8
            $0.right == $0.superview!.right - 8
        }  
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is loop through my array of BlockViews and run `print(blockView.frame)` and see frames that aren't zero.

Now I know I'm setting my `frame` to `.zero` inside of the `BlockView.init`. That's because I'd like the view to size itself based on its labels.

Is there a function I need to run to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: While I personally do not use frames (auto layout instead), from the sounds of things you *cannot* do this. Both are based on view and their controller lifecycles. And yes, **both** have not clue of their "frame" on `init` - unless the controller is *either* far enough along to give*it's* view's frame *or* a specific frame is supplied. So I guess the question is - what `UIViewController` code do you have that may help?

Comment: I always use auto layout. The tricky part I'm facing that I want to either add the view as a subview if it'll fit without overflowing or I want to create a new view controller for the UIPageViewController and *then* add the element in. Which requires sizing

Comment: Is there any constraints with BlockView? Manually frame set will not work if constraints added.

Comment: I'm not setting any constraints yet with each BlockView relative to their eventual superviews. I'm not even adding them to a view yet, I'm just trying to get their prospective size based on their contents so I can determine whether to add them to an existing page on the UIPageViewController or to create a new page and then add

Comment: Have you tried creating a new UI context (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`) and getting the size? I don't know if it will work, but I create a complex user-driven mask image of `UIViews` this way. Basically I'm creating an image of things based on a displayed set of views. Maybe combined with using `sizeThatFits` you can "display" it in a context the size you choose - without actually displaying it on the screen - to calculate the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`sizeThatFits(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits) to calculate it without putting it to the superview. The only parameter to the method is the `CGSize` that represents boundaries in which it should be displayed. E.g., if you know the width of the superview (e.g., 340 points) and you want to know how much it will take in height:

```
let expectedSize = view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 340, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
```

However, your `BlockView` does not seem to have a proper constraints set yet. You initialize it with `super.init(frame: .zero)` - thus it has size 0,0.

And your constraints does not change that, e.g.:

```
constrain(primaryLabel) {
   $0.centerY == $0.superview!.centerY
   $0.left == $0.superview!.left + 8
}
```

This looks like you set the center in Y axis of the label to the center of the block view, and the left anchor of the label to the left anchor of the view. If the `blockView` would have the size already, that would position the label properly. But right now the size of the block view is not affected by the size of labels at all. I guess you would want to constrain the labels to the left, right, top and bottom anchors of the `blockView`, so that when you try to calculate the size of the `blockView`, the autolayout will have to first calculate the size of the labels and based on this the size of the `blockView` itself.

A possible solution (I am using anchor based autolayout syntax) that you can try to put to initializer of the `BlockView`:

```
primaryLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
primaryLabel.topAchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
primaryLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
primaryLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondaryLabel.topAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
secondaryLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
secondaryLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
secondaryLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

Comment: This assumes that view has a size though, right? I'm running this, `let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 24.0` `print(view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)))` and getting (0,0)

Comment: I updated my original post with new constraints based on your answer but am still getting (0,0) running `sizeThatFits`

Comment: I guess you still have to set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: in the block view?

Comment: yeah.. plus it has to be set on the primaryLabel too.. but I guess that library of yours that you use for constraints does that for you.. but just to be sure, you can set it on label too